# Three.js : JSONLoader + loadAjaxJSON

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

As I handle heavy models I'm trying to display dynamicaly the loaded percentage while loading JSON, so I've made a rough test with [loadAjaxJSON method](http://threejs.org/docs/58/#Reference/Loaders/JSONLoader)...

The following loading returns the percentage during loading, but never reach the callback function.

Is it due to a missing declaration, to a wrong context parameter, to something else ? I can't find documentation about that.

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader( true );
loader.loadAjaxJSON(
            document,           // < context ??
            'try.js',
            function ( geometry, materials ) { CreateScene( geometry, materials ); },
            false,              // < texturePath
            function( progress, result ) { console.log((progress.loaded / progress.total * 100).toFixed());}
            )
```

Console :

```
7 13 20 .. 100
TypeError: a.parse is not a function [three.min.js (ligne 204)]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes it's faster too look into the sources instead of looking for documentation. Here is the code of JSONLoader: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/loaders/JSONLoader.js .
As you see context should contain two methods: 
parse and onLoadComplete. Basically you just need to send loader as context, look into the shortcut for loadAjaxJSON - method load.
About texturePath, also in the method load you can see how it should look like:

```
texturePath = texturePath && ( typeof texturePath === "string" ) ? texturePath : this.extractUrlBase( url );
```

if you look deeper you can see that extractUrlBase will return './' so in your case your code should look like this:

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader( true );
loader.loadAjaxJSON(
        loader,           // context 
        'try.js',
        function ( geometry, materials ) { CreateScene( geometry, materials ); },
        './', // texturePath or loader.extractUrlBase('try.js'), 
        function( progress, result ) { console.log((progress.loaded / progress.total * 100).toFixed());}
        )
```

Comment: Well I confess I'm not yet on a level with decoding prototypes.. but this is a good lesson. Thanks a lot, it works.